# sorting list of integers in data file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to input a data file(which has a list of integers) in a python program 
sort it and write it out in a different data file.
This is what I did

```
import math

f = open(numeric.data, 'r')
print f
o = open ('filteredNumeric.data', 'w')
print o

f.sort()


o.write(f)

o.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. What is the exact error? What have you done so far?

Comment: i got character buffered object error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

with open('numeric.data', 'r') as infile, open ('filteredNumeric.data', 'w') as outfile:

    list_ = [ float(line) for line in infile ]
    list_.sort()

    outfile.writelines('{}\n'.format(element) for element in list_)
```

Comment: yes, thats what I want, but I want the out file in integers so i changed it to `list_ = [ int(line for line in infile ]`
Thanks!